# Does the varying of aperture influence the camera calibration?

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I am calibrating an industrial AVT camera. Is it ok, when I focus on the plane where I will do my measurements with the f/4 aperture then close the aperture to f/16, calibrate the internal parameters of the camera and then open the aperture to f/4 ? Will the calibration change with the changing aperture? I know that none of the parameters (focal length, principal point, lens) should physically change, but is there no effect?

I am not changing the focus (focal length). I need to change the aperture due to bigger depth of field during my calibration and faster camera during my measurements.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optics, not programming.

Comment: it depends on which 'internal parameters' you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the short answer is: No it doesn't.

The calibration should be the same (within experimental limits) at different apertures. The aperture only affects the depth of field and the amount of light entering the camera. The focal length, principal point, len distortions, etc. don't change - although your ability to measure them accuratley may be affected by the quality of the image you get.

Maybe a larger aperture could in theory capture a better approximation of lens distortion, although [reading this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703113117/http://toothwalker.org:80/optics/distortion.html) makes me doubt my own words, but if you calibrate at a wide aperture and then capture at a smaller aperture, this should not be a problem. Only if your lens is seriously distorted would it be an issue (IMHO). The article linked says this:

> The size of the stop has no effect on the distortion, as the chief ray
>   does not alter its route when the aperture is made smaller or larger.

It would presumably be a simple procedure to perform camera calibration at different aperture settings and see if the results are similar. Certainly I know of no way to infer the aperture setting from a camera calibration matrix, which implies that this information itself is not captured.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your lens and exactly what values you are calibrating.
If you are just setting the back focus distance, then there is no problem.
Or if you are only measuring in the center of the field of view.

Without knowing the focal length, widest aperture, and the general
quality of the lens, it's not possible to give a specific answer.
For example, if the widest aperture is f/1.4, then the lens should 
perform well at f/4.  But if f/4 *is* the widest aperture, chances 
are you will see a lot of aberrations.

Generally speaking, if you start with the widest aperture of a camera
lens and stop down, the resolving power in the center of the field of 
view increases for about 2 stops, and the resolving power in the periphery 
of the field improves for about 4 stops.

Beyond that, if you continue to stop down, there is no improvement in
image quality (only increased depth-of-field and a dimmer image--as a 
previous answer correctly states).  Eventually, as the physical diameter 
of the f/stop becomes small,  resolving power throughout the field will
decrease due to diffraction.

For example, on a "full frame" (35 x 24 mm format)  digital camera with 
a good lens, f/22 is noticeably less sharp than say, f/8.

Unfortunately, geometrical (Gaussian) analysis cannot predict
the behavior of real lenses, for two reasons: aberrations and
distortion.

Aberrations are imperfections  in design, materials and/or 
manufacturing that can be corrected by additional elements, better
glass, closer manufacturing tolerances, etc-- but only to a point 
and only at a price.  Ideal lenses exist only in theory; real lenses 
always perform best (i.e. greatest resolving power) for paraxial rays 
(traveling near the optical axis).

Not all aberrations are equally affected by stopping down.
Most improvement: higher-order spherical
Much improvement: spherical, oblique spherical and coma
Some improvement: astigmatism, field curvature, axial chromatic
Not affected: lateral chromatic

Geometrical (Petzval) distortion (technically not an aberration)
also is not affected by stopping down.

Diffraction on the other hand, is a fundamental  law of optics--you
just have to live with it.  Diffraction varies inversely with the
physical diameter of the aperture: the smaller the diameter, the bigger
the angular size of the Airy disk. As we all know, f-number is focal 
length divided by diameter--so f/16 is a much smaller hole on f=50 mm 
lens than on a f=150 mm lens.

Traditional methods of measuring diffraction and confusion by
diameters at the projected image (film or sensor) -- rather than by 
resolving power at the object--tend to understate the performance of
longer lenses and depth-of-field of larger formats.   But MTF charts 
tell the real  story about the former: the best performing lens in 
any manufacture's  catalog is a long lens or telephoto.

understate the performance of longer focal length lenses.

Diffraction  is why pinholes -- which have no aberrations (and no 
distortions if  properly designed) -- are not sharp.

Smaller aperture diameters always have more diffraction (i.e., a
larger Airy disk), but diffraction is only significant when the
Airy disk is larger than the lens's circle-of-confusion.  The better
correct the lens, the close it is to being "limited by diffraction"
--the technical term for an ideal optical system.

More information:
https://www.diyphotography.net/what-actually-happens-when-you-stop-down-a-lens/